# How far should best practices like avoiding magic number should go?

Tags: java, coding-style

In near future we might be enforced by a rule by which we can not have any hard coded numbers in our java source code.  All the hard coded numbers must be declared as `final` variables.

Even though this sounds great in theory it is really hard/tedious to implement in code, especially legacy code.  Should it really be considered "best practice" to declare numbers in following code snippets as `final` variables?

```
//creating excel
cellnum = 0;

//Declaring variables. 
Object[] result = new Object[2];

//adding dash to ssn
return ssn.substring(1, 3)+"-"+ssn.substring(3, 5)+"-"+ssn.substring(5, 9);
```

Above are just some of the examples I could think of, but in these (and others) where would you as a developer say enough is enough?

I wanted to make this question a community wiki but couldn't see how...?

Comment: what does `final` accomplishes besides making you look somewhere out of the code, if anything parsing there would require pluggable regular expression to make it versatile.

Comment: believers believe making one variable final and reusing it in other places will be of benefit when something value needs to be changed, however, that theory does not make sense when declaring arrays or substring an ssn that will _always_ be 9 digits

Comment: the question was solely for the ssn example.

Comment: Your `ssn` statement indexes are off-by-one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely **no**. Literal constants have their places, especially low constants such as `0`, `1`, `2`, ...

I don't think anyone would think

```
double[] pair = new double[PAIR_COUNT];
```

makes more sense than

```
double[] pair = new double[2];
```

I'd say use final variables if

- ...it increases readability,
- ...the value may change (and is used in multiple places), or
- ...it serves as documentation

---

A related side note: As always with coding standards / conventions: very few (if any) rules should be followed strictly.

Comment: good. I'm of the same opinion.  It needs to be controlled rather than tagging every _number_ as a hardcoded number

Comment: And also checks for 0 length strings etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Right :-)  `if (index < 0 || index > arr.length) throw ...` vs `if (index < MIN_ARRAY_INDEX || index > arr.length) throw ...` for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Replacing numbers by constants makes sense if the number carries a meaning that is not inherently obvious by looking at its value alone.

For instance,

```
productType = 221; // BAD: the number needs to be looked up somewhere to understand its meaning
productType = PRODUCT_TYPE_CONSUMABLE; // GOOD: the constant is self-describing
```

On the other hand,

```
int initialCount = 0; // GOOD: in this context zero really means zero
int initialCount = ZERO; // BAD: the number value is clear, and there's no need to add a self-referencing constant name if there's no other meaning
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if a literal has a special meaning, it should be given a unique name rather than assuming things. I'm not sure why it is "practically" hard/tedious to do the same.

`Object[] result = new Object[2];` => seems like a good candidate for using a Pair class

`cellnum = 0;` => cellnum = FIRST_COLUMN; esp since you might end up using an API which treats 1 as the starting index or maybe you want to process an excel in which columns start from 2.

`return ssn.substring(1, 3)+"-"+ssn.substring(3, 5)+"-"+ssn.substring(5, 9)` => If you have code like this littered throughout your codebase, you have bigger problems. If this code exists in a single location and is shielded by a sane API, I don't really see a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen folks consider 0 and 1 accepted exceptions.

The idea is that you want to document why you have two Objects as above for example.
I agree with you about the dashes in SSN. The comment describes it better than 4 named constants.

In general, I like the idea of no magic numbers, but as with every rule, there are pragmatics involved. Legacy code, brings its own issues. It's a lot of work without a lot of productivity in terms of changed behavior to bring old code up to date this way. I would consider doing it in an evolutionary fashion: when you have to edit an old file, bring it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the context doesn't it. If there are numbers in the code that does not indicate why they exist then naming them makes teh code more readable. If you see the number 3.14 in code is it PI? is there any way to tell or is that just a coincidence? Naming it PI will clear up the mystery.

In your example, why is cellnum = 2? why not 10? or 20? That should be named something, say INITIAL_CELL or MAX_CELL. Expecially if this same number, meaning the same thing appears again in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if it needs to be changed. Or for that matter, it can be changed.

If you only need 2 objects (say, for a pair like aioobe mentioned) then that isn't a **magic** number, it's the **correct** number. If it's for a variable tuple that, at this moment, is 2, then you probably should abstract it out into a constant.